# How to loop object to fragment and retrieve bundle

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-bundle

I have 2 arrays that I am trying to loop out, and then package as an object and send it to another fragment to be retrieved as a bundle and then access that bundle, but I am getting a null pointer.

In Fragment 1, I have the following method:

```
public Fragment getQuestionFragments(String[] array_id, String[] array1) {

        int count = 0;

        for (String x : array_id) {

            Question question = new Question();
            question.setQuestionNumber(x);
            question.setQuestion(array1[count]);
            question_list.add(question);
            count++;

            ViewPagerFragmentActivity.newInstance(question);

        }

        goToQuestions();

        return null;
    }
```

Then in Fragment 2 I retrieve the looped out question object as follows:

```
 public static ViewPagerFragmentActivity newInstance(Question question)
    {
        ViewPagerFragmentActivity f = new ViewPagerFragmentActivity();
        Bundle bdl = new Bundle(2);
        bdl.putString("QuestionID", question.getQuestionNumber());
        bdl.putString("QuestionString", question.getQuestionString());
        f.setArguments(bdl);
        return f;
    }
```

When I try and access the QuestionID from the bundle, using `question = (Question) getArguments().get("QuestionID");` it throws a null pointer.

From what I have read, I felt this was correct, but I am obviously missing something. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably have to post more code to fix all the issues as there seem to be a few.  But the big issue that I see here is you are trying to instantiate an Activity, rather than using the Android system to do it for you.  In your newInstance method, you need to change it to create an intent which the Android OS uses to launch your activity.  So you need to change your newInstance method to be like this:

```
public static Intent newInstance(Context context, Question question)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ViewPagerFragmentActivity.class);
    intent.putString("QuestionID", question.getQuestionNumber());
    intent.putString("QuestionString", question.getQuestionString());
    return intent;
}
```

Then you need to start that activity from your current in order to see it:

```
startActivity(ViewPagerFragmentActivity.newIntent(this, question));
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to do within your loop and more information is likely needed to solve whatever you are trying to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing [@tim.paetz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1236327/tim-paetz) answer, you're trying cast a String to a Question object, because you have putted a String in your intent:

```
bdl.putString("QuestionID", question.getQuestionNumber());
```

So in your case the right way to get the object is not like you have done:

```
question = (Question) getArguments().get("QuestionID");
```

But one of many ways can be:

```
String questionId = getArguments().getString("QuestionID");
Question question = //find in the database with this id
```